# Get selected values from jQuery: sol.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I'm using this plugin to have a `Select` tag with `checkbox` and `search` at the same time

https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Seachable-Option-List-with-Checkboxes.html

Currently I have this working code for sol.js

```
       <label for="demoSOL" class="svs-small"><small>Task List</small></label>
       <select id="demoSOL" name="myTask" class="mdb-select multi-sol-svs" 
        multiple="multiple">
       <optgroup label="Task List" title="Opiton Group 1">
       @if(count($task_record))
       @foreach($task_record as $field)
       <option title="Subgroup 1" value="{{$field->taskCode}}"> 
       {{$field->task_title}}</option>
       @endforeach
       @else
            <option value="" title="Subgroup 1">No record found..</option>
       @endif
  </optgroup>
  </select>
```

JavaScript

`$('#demoSOL').searchableOptionList();`

How can I get the values of the `select` ? in javascript when the user selects some checkboxes inside of the select?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer

```
var taskData = []; 
$("input:checkbox[name=myTask]:checked").each(function() { 
    taskData.push($(this).val()); 
}); 

alert(taskData);
```